# Apex tabular form lost when validation matched

Tags: validation, oracle-apex

I set a validation in my tabular form, when the validation match and fired then I get the below msg and my tabular form lost, but if the validation does not match and did not fire the it works fine.

> Current tabular form data is too old; the source data has been
>   modified. Click here to discard your changes and reload the data from
>   the database.

validation type is 
PL/SQL Function (returning error text)

code is

```
DECLARE

ERR VARCHAR2(500);

BEGIN

IF :salary < 2000 THEN

ERR := 'INCORRECT';

END IF;

RETURN ERR;

END;
```

Comment: What version of apex you have and did you changed the Application Primary Language for something different than english?

Comment: Anything worth mentioning regarding your tabular form setup? Anything in the query (always helps to show your sql)? Did you change any metadata after the form was created? (changed display types, removed or added columns)? Tabular forms are by far the buggiest section in apex and regularly go wrong when metadata is changed (or should change). So it really helps to recall the changes you made to it.

Comment: Hello  Cristian, no i did not change the the language

Comment: Hello Tom, actually i added some virtual columns in my tabular form, and add changed the wide of the textboxes but did not change anything else you mentioned.

Comment: Tom! plz note that the virtual column are required in my case

Comment: Cristian! i am using apex 5.0